# setting a new independent variable changes all the other variables in c

Tags: c, malloc

I really don't know which title fits better to describe my problem. I'm using Linux through VirtualBox. I'm using the gcc compiler. I have been writing my code up until now (300 lines) without a similar problem. Suddenly, if I put a new variable and set a value, the other variables in my code change their values.
I am wondering if I have to clean a memory or something.

```
do
{
    rand_arr = rpermute(dim_x * dim_y);
    flag = 0;

    for (t = 0; t < (dim_x * dim_y); t++)
    {
        x = rand_arr[t] / dim_x;
        y = rand_arr[t] % dim_x;

        if (arr[x][y] == 255)
        {
            current_distance = sqrt(pow(exit[0][0] - x, 2) + pow(exit[0][1] - y, 2));

            if (x != 0 && arr[x - 1][y] != 254)
            {
                distance_up = sqrt(pow(exit[0][0] - (x - 1), 2) + pow(exit[0][1] - y, 2));
            }
            else
            {
                distance_up = max_distance + 10000000;
            }

            // Here there is a code computing similar math operations as
            // current_distance and distance_up

            min_dist[0] = distance_up;
            min_dist[1] = distance_back;

            // Here i continue setting in the min_dist array all the variables
            // Here there is a bubblesort code to arrange the min_dist array

            k = 0;
            do
            {
                if (distance_up == min_dist[k] && arr[x - 1][y] == 0 && distance_up < current_distance)
                {
                    arr[x - 1][y] = 255;
                    arr[x][y] = 0;
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else if (distance_back == min_dist[k] && arr[x][y - 1] == 0 && distance_back < current_distance)
                {
                    arr[x][y - 1] = 255;
                    arr[x][y] = 0;
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }

                // Here there is a code with if statements similar to the two above

                k++;
            } while (k < 4  &&  min_dist[k] < current_distance);
        }
    }
    ...
} while (...)
```

So every variable before this loop remains the same, but if I just set a new variable, for example `int test=0;`, every variable changes in this loop despite the fact that the new variable is independent.
I am also using `malloc` in a function; I wonder if this is the problem but I didn't have any problem till now.

Comment: can you provide us with some sort of source code to check?

Comment: Post the code in here if the problem persists.

Comment: my code is 300 lines, and i can't understand which part would be helpful for you

Comment: can i post the whole code here?

Comment: No, don't post the whole code. Reduce it to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You might even find your issue while doing that.

Comment: I found that it's a buffer oveflow problem because of malloc

Comment: Stop using TABs to indent code, it's a mess!

Comment: This code is much much too long.  It's your task to strip away everything that does not affect this issue.  Don't expect us to wade through many lines of code that are unrelated.

Comment: @meaning-matters what should i use to make the code easier to be read?

Comment: @user3143155 It's not about making it easier to read, it about presenting as little code as possible so that you end up with solely the fundamental issue you're having.  For example: Strip away statements, this will of course make the code do something else but that's not important. For example you have 8 `distance_` variables and code, start deleting them one-by-one to see if the problem disappears, etc.
Then stop using TABs!!!  Look at your code above, the indentation is shit.

Comment: In general: You're asking a favour here, put great effort in showing as little code as possible, writing as clearly as possible, and making sure that code looks great.

Comment: @meaning-matters changed the code i hope its small enough, sorry i'm new here

Comment: @user3143155 Indentation is still a mess.  And please use spaces around binary operators consistently.

Comment: If declaring a new variable changes the behaviour of the code, that smells of stack corruption. How many of those arrays are statically allocated, and are they definitely the right size?

Comment: @user3143155 Nope, you still use TABs, indentation looks bad, and you still don't use spaces consistently.  Good luck, I'm not spending more time on this.

Comment: Too many crucial information does not show up in your code, such as the definitions of `arr` and `min_dist`, and where you put the `int test = 0;` statement? To debug this kind of problem, the whole code (can be compiled successfully) is usually needed.

Comment: @Notlikethat 3 arrays in my code are statically allocated and they definitely are the right size, on the other hand only one is dynamically allocated with malloc, the rand_arr

Comment: `if (distance_up == min_dist[k] && arr[x - 1][y] == 0 && distance_up < current_distance)` **--->>** is it guaranteed that `x > 0` here ? (this pattern occurs three times IICC) x=0 would result in out-of-bounds access to the array

Comment: I've reformatted the code for you, using [`uncrustify`](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) and my preferred settings (which may not be yours). You have a memory trampling problem. The (mis)use of `malloc()`'d space might be a factor.  The `rpermute()` function appears to be a random permutation (presumably of the values [0..N) or [1..N], where N is `dim_x * dim_y`.  There are a number of other arrays that could be being abused.  You can use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org) on the code; that will help if it is heap abuse (rather than stack abuse).

Comment: @wildplasser yes it is guaranteed, if i don't use malloc the code works fine

Comment: @wildplasser At least one of the `x` is zero, maybe this is the problem. Here is the code of `rpermute`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922765/gnu-buffer-overflow-using-malloc

Comment: It certainly is the error, similar for y, somewhere.

Comment: @wildplasser the distance_up == min_dist[k] prevents the x to be zero,that's why i have it first in the if statement, i think that if this is false it will not check the next arr[x - 1][y] == 0. I have to say again that if i don't use malloc my code works without any problems.

Comment: Just put the asserts into the code to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <assert.h> /* <<-- Here */

do
{
    rand_arr = rpermute(dim_x * dim_y);
    flag = 0;

    for (t = 0; t < (dim_x * dim_y); t++)
    {
        x = rand_arr[t] / dim_x;
        y = rand_arr[t] % dim_x;

        if (arr[x][y] == 255)
        {
            current_distance = sqrt(pow(exit[0][0] - x, 2) + pow(exit[0][1] - y, 2));

            if (x != 0 && arr[x - 1][y] != 254)
            {
                distance_up = sqrt(pow(exit[0][0] - (x - 1), 2) + pow(exit[0][1] - y, 2));
            }
            else
            {
                distance_up = max_distance + 10000000;
            }

            // Here there is a code computing similar math operations as
            // current_distance and distance_up

            min_dist[0] = distance_up;
            min_dist[1] = distance_back;

            // Here i continue setting in the min_dist array all the variables
            // Here there is a bubblesort code to arrange the min_dist array

            k = 0;
            do
            {
                if (distance_up == min_dist[k] && arr[x - 1][y] == 0 && distance_up < current_distance)
                {
                    assert (x > 0); // <<-- Here
                    arr[x - 1][y] = 255;
                    arr[x][y] = 0;
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else if (distance_back == min_dist[k] && arr[x][y - 1] == 0 && distance_back < current_distance)
                {
                    assert (y > 0); // <<--- Here
                    arr[x][y - 1] = 255;
                    arr[x][y] = 0;
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }

                // Here there is a code with if statements similar to the two above

                k++;
            } while (k < 4  &&  min_dist[k] < current_distance);
        }
    }
    ...
} while (1); // <<-- Here
```

Comment: Next step: declare all variables you use as index as unsigned. See if the behaviour changes.

Comment: now it's even worse. i used free() after malloc, valgrind now gives me zero errors but the problem still persists!

Comment: @user3143155: Change all the array variables allocated on the stack into arrays allocated via `malloc()`. This will allow `valgrind` to help diagnoses abuses. It will also completely change the memory usage on the stack.  (Make sure you're working with a good VCS or good copies of the code!)  Somewhere, it seems highly probable that you're abusing a stack-allocated array.