# GNU buffer overflow using malloc

Tags: c, malloc, overflow, buffer, gnu

I am running in a loop the following function:

```
int* rpermute(int n)
{
    int* a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int  k;

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
       a[k] = k;
    }

    for (k = n - 1; k > 0; k--)
    {
       int j    = rand() % (k + 1);
       int temp = a[j];
       a[j]     = a[k];
       a[k]     = temp;
   }

   return a;
}
```

If I set a new int variable in my code every variable is changing, I assume it is a buffer overflow problem.

Running the valgrind i get the following:

```
==4459== 73,036 bytes in 19 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1

==4459==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

==4459==    by 0x402CFB: rpermute (in /home/giwrgos/Desktop/crowdv22/crowd_evacuation)

==4459==    by 0x403378: main (in /home/giwrgos/Desktop/crowdv22/crowd_evacuation)
```

I use linux through the virtualbox but I have set enough storage and ram, what should I do?

Comment: Does the calling function `free` the result given by `rpermute` ?

Comment: "if i set a new int variable in my code " - what does this mean? "every variable is changing" - what variables exactly? In this function? Elsewhere? Please see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). (That valgrind message is "just" a leak, not an overflow.)

Comment: I am not sure if i understood what you said, i set to an array in my main code the result from rpermute, i use it and rpermute gives me a new result because i have it in a loop

Comment: `what should I do`: Call it with a small enouh value and debug it.

Comment: In a loop i have the function rpermute that gives me a shuffled array, after that in the same loop i have some mathematical operations with variables, so if i just set a new independent int variable in my main code the variables in the loop change! What can i do to avoid this leak?

Comment: @Devolus the problem persists even if i call it with a small value in the loop, do i have to set a bigger memory somewhere or to clean a memory somehow?

Comment: Show us the loop your are talking about, and explain what you expected and what you actually got, that would be helpful.

Comment: Yoiu must debug it. At first glance your cod elooks fine. Are you sure that the overflow happens here? I haven't debugged it, just reading it, but I don't see any obvious problems with it.

Comment: @leeduhem [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913069/setting-a-new-independent-variable-changes-all-the-other-variables-in-c?noredirect=1#comment31411205_20913069  my loop is here, if i set in my code a new int variable for example int test=0; everything in this loop is changing (current_distance,distance_up...), on the other hand if i set a new double everything is fine

Comment: @Devolus [link] stackoverflow.com/questions/20913069/… my loop is here, if i set in my code a new int variable for example int test=0; everything in this loop is changing (current_distance,distance_up...), on the other hand if i set a new double everything is fine

Comment: Stop using TABs to indent please, it results in a mess.

Comment: I just put this function in a loop of 1000 and I didn't have a single overwrite. Also stepped through it as well as making sure it works with 0 and 1 and everything is ok. I'm pretty sure that your problems is in some other part of the code, and this particular error is just a symptom of it. If you can observe that variables are changing randomly, you can use a memory access breakpoint and watch where this happens.

Comment: Please see @user3143155 comment in my answer: There's nothing wrong with this code, it's somewhere else.

Comment: (side note) Don't forget to verify that `malloc` succeeded.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu what do you mean?

Comment: @user3143155, `malloc` can fail; there might not be enough memory, so it returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: See poster's comment below, the problem is **not** in this code after all.

You should simply `free()` the memory allocated in and returned by `rpermute()`.  This must be done in the code from where you call `rpermute()`, once you're done with this array.

I understand that you regenerate this array for differing `int` values (the `n` parameter of `rpermute()`).  Perhaps you simply assign a new output to the array you keep:

```
int* array;
...
array = rpermute(100);

// Some time later.
array = rpermute(200);  // Previous array memory is leaking.
```

You should do instead:

```
free(array);
array = rpermute(200);
```

Note that this is not a 'buffer over flow', but a memory leak instead.  I checked you code for buffer overflow: index of `a` points outside it, but this seemed to be ok in both loops.

Comment: i just tried free() as you pointed but the problem persists. I always have the same n parameter for rpermute, rpermute just gives me every time the same amount of numbers shuffled

Comment: So where is that buffer overflow happening?

Comment: My problem is not in this part of the code, if use rpermute with a simple main code its fine but when i use it here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913069/setting-a-new-independent-variable-changes-all-the-other-variables-in-c?noredirect=1#comment31411205_20913069    the variables current_distance,distance_up ... are changing if i set a new independent int variable in my main code

Comment: @user3143155 Then it's a mistake to post this code! I had a look at the other code: Way too long, don't expect us to wade through hundreds of unrelated lines.  It's your task to minimise the number of lines, and you may find what you did wrong yourself by doing so.